# MySQL with Haskell on Windows

Tags: mysql, haskell

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database with haskell. I have tried to install `hdbc-mysql` and `mysql-simple` but I get a

`setup.exe: The program 'mysql_config' is required but it could not be found`

Can anyone please help with getting either of those installed or point me to an alternative that works.

I am on windows 10.

Comment: IMO, [persistent-mysql](https://www.stackage.org/package/persistent-mysql), is a better library.

Comment: @sibi thanks, but this is the same problem. It requires `mysql_config`. I don't know how to get this working on a windows machine

Comment: This may help you: https://github.com/bos/mysql/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

Did you install mysql client?

If you didn't, install mysql client first.

If you did, then check whether `mysql_config --version` prints version or not in cmd.

When above command didn't work, find the **mysql_config** program and add it to your path environment variable.

Comment: do you mean any mysql client?

Comment: Hm... I mean, mysql client of mysql(oracle)

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what you mean. Do you mean MySQL Workbench? I am on mysql.com trying to find `mysql client` ?

Comment: It seems that on windows the mysql_config is a perl script called "mysql_config.pl" located under MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\bin


But the link posted in the comments of the question shows that there is no straight forward solution to have the build accepting the perl script instead of an executable.